# WinForms UserControl gets cut off when running

Tags: c#, winforms, anchor

I'm having a lot of difficulty with WinForms and sizing of user controls. We've got a DataGrid, with some buttons underneath it, in a custom User Control.

[image]

Everything is anchored correctly. As in, when you resize the control, the buttons stay anchored to their proper sides, and the data grid fills the rest.

It even works when adding it to our main form:

[image]

Then, when we run the app, it gets cut off:

[image]

I've tried:

- Docking
- Anchoring
- Changing the `AutoSize` property of the control, and the control as used in the main form

But nothing is getting it to act like it does in the designer.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: if you make the datagrid invisible what does the screen look like?

Comment: Then it's simply a gray background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were obvious issues with the WinForms app, WRT scaling and fonts. We switched over to WPF and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Split Container` and put `dataGridView` on top and bottom insert your buttons and set `Panel` that is in bottom `Fixed`.

Another option is to use  `TableLayoutPanel`

More information :

[Designing the Layout of Windows Forms using a TableLayoutPanel, with auto-expand panels](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/842418/Designing-the-Layout-of-Windows-Forms-using-a)

Comment: I would go for the `TableLayoutPanel`.